# Curl - checking connection

Tags: c++, curl

I used Curl 7.2.9 and checked connection this way:

Here's example:

```
curl = curl_easy_init();
bool result = false;
if(curl)
{
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, m_checkConnectionUrl);
    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
}
if(res != CURLE_OK)
{

}
else
{
    // connection is available
}
```

Now I switched to curl-7.33.0 and got *CURLE_WRITE_ERROR* error,
and to make it work I must code it like

```
std::string output;
char* encodedUrl = curl_easy_escape(curl, m_checkConnectionUrl, 0);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, encodedUrl);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writeMemoryCurlCallbackStub);
CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

But I don't need to write anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manily the Curl option *CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION* is used to have a certain amount of data periodically(at the callback functoin) to handle a large file download. I don't see any reason to use this with your curl purpose, regardless the version.

Remove the *CURLOPT_POST*(by default its 0) and *CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION* from the code and it should work. If it doesn't, then you are doing something wrong at other places in your code!

Also, if you are checking whether the URL is ok or not, then using CURL is ok. But to only check for connection, you can only check whether the port 80 of the domain is on or not.

Comment: removing CURLOPT_POST and CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION didn't help - the same error occurs. The url is "google.com". I just want to check if the internet connection is available

Comment: what exact error you get? also, does it work with google with the earlier version?

Comment: I get error 23 CURLE_WRITE_ERROR. Of course it works with the earlier version as I mentioned above

Comment: Use CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to handle redirect. If it doesn't work, then run the code with enabling verbose mode CURLOPT_VERBOSE with 1.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I have just encountered a similar problem. After some more googling this is the solution:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY, 1L);
curl_easy_perform(curl);
// OK, now we are connected (if nothing bad happened), 
// but it would be nice to communicate with the server: 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY, 0L);
//now we can do the actual communication
```

I used this to separate authentication from the actual emails sending.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a writecallback as well

```
size_t CurlWriteCallback(char* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* up)
{ 
    TRACE("CURL - Response received:\n%s", buf);
    TRACE("CURL - Response handled %d bytes:\n%s", size*nmemb);

    // tell curl how many bytes we handled
    return size*nmemb;
}


  if(curl)
{
     curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &CurlWriteCallback);
     curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, m_checkConnectionUrl);
    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
}
```